# Best practices regarding allowing many different types to constructors?

Tags: java

I have a class called RawReader that reads the bytes of some resource, parses them, then writes files to an output directory.

It makes sense to allow different types to be passed in as the source and destination to the constructor.

- Source: String (of file or URL), URL, File or InputStream
- Destination: String (directory) or File

However if I overload the constructor that leaves me with 8 different versions. If I wanted to add a third optional argument for example `chunkSize` *I'd have 16 constructors!*

On the other hand I could just have two constructors accepting `(Object, Object)` and `(Object, Object, int)`. The argument types could be detected and an IllegalArgumentExceptions thrown if they aren't correct.

**How are situations like this normally handled in Java?**

Comment: This is why I often think constructors are evil - they do multiply like rabbits!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java):

```
Foo foo = new FooBuilder().setFile(..).setChunkSize().build();
```

Where `.build()` invokes a constructor of `Foo` that takes the builder and assigns whichever variables are set. Something like that:

public class Foo {

```
private Foo(FooBuilder builder) {
    //get whatever you can find from the builder to fill the state of Foo
}
public static FooBuilder {
     private String filename;
     private File file;
     private InputStream stream;
     private int chunkSize;
     // getters and setters
     public Foo build() {
         return new Foo(this);
     }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) After reading it I had a look around and found an [example on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java) which creates a new object inside the builder than returns that object rather than passing itself to the constructor. Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: doesn't matter, it's a matter of preference I guess

Answer (score 0):

First of all an idea with `(Object, Object, int)` is terrible, don't go that way! You loose strong-typing, IDE assistance and API clarity.

On your place I would restrict the constructor to most obvious/low-level input you can take and provide a builder/factory methods:

```
RawReader reader = RawReaderBuilder.
  withInput(inputStream).
  withOutput(someFile).
  withChunkSize().
  build();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find you have constructors with the same signature, you can use factory methods with different names:

```
public class Foo {

    public static Foo createForDir(String dir) {
        // create a Foo as you like and return it
    }

    public static Foo createForUrl(String url) {
        // create a Foo as you like and return it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It makes sense to allow different types to be passed in as the source
>   and destination to the constructor.

Up to a point. However it doesn't make much sense to provide conversions that the caller could just as easily provide himself, especially if it's going to lead to as many as eight constructors. So:

(a) You don't need both `String` and `File`. Decide on one, and stick to it. I would use `File`. That already divides the number of constructors by four.

(b) You don't really need both `URL` and `InputStream` either, although there are precedents. Getting rid of 'URL' would divide the number by two.